# Import an artifact registry from a different project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a production and a development project in GCP. Each project runs a cloud function. At the moment i have an artifact registry repository that gets imported to the dev function when the function is deployed. Is there a way to import the dev artifact repository to the production cloud function in the requirments.txt? I've tried to add the import in the requirements as it's done in the development one but I'm getting an error. how can this be done?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Reuse artifact? reuse container? reuse Cloud Function code? It's not really clear

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i want to import the dev registry to the production cloud function requirements.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install your libraries, you notify the index url where to find the packages

```
#File requirement.txt
extra-index-url https://<region>-python.pkg.dev/<PROJECT_ID>/<your-repo-name>/
my-package
```

In that index URL, you can specify the region, the project ID and the repo name.

You can use the same in dev and in production environment. However, you have to grant the Cloud Functions build process to access the repo in another project.

Cloud Functions packaging (a container) is built with Cloud Build (and use Buildpack, but it does not matter here). Because of Cloud Build use, you have to grant the Cloud Build service account the permission to access in read mode to your dev repository.

So, grant the Cloud Build service account of your prod project (pattern `<Project Number>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`) the role `roles/artifactregistry.reader`. You can grant it at the project level (globally for your dev project) or only at the repository level (better, least privilege principle).